# JAVA : Getting .class from a external Class

Tags: rest, jar, jersey, classloader, external

I tried to load a class from a external JAR. It is a Jersey servlet. To add the servlet to the Servlet Container i call the Jersey Application Class. But the Resource is not accessible from browser. I need .class from the external loaded class, but how ?

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    private Object external;

    public ApplicationConfig() {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        String pathToJar = someJAR;
        try {
            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(pathToJar);
            Enumeration enumeration = jarFile.entries();

            URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" +pathToJar+"!/")};
            URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
            while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
                JarEntry je = (JarEntry) enumeration.nextElement();
                if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
                    continue;
                }
                String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
                className = className.replace("/",".");
                if(className.contains("HelloWorldServlet")) {
                    System.out.println(className);
                    external = cl.loadClass(className).newInstance();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(HelloServlet.class);
        classes.add(external.getClass().getClass());

        return super.getClasses();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    private Class<?> external;

    public ApplicationConfig() {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        String pathToJar = someJAR;
        try {
            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(pathToJar);
            Enumeration enumeration = jarFile.entries();

            URL[] urls = { new URL("jar:file:" +pathToJar+"!/")};
            URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
            while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
                JarEntry je = (JarEntry) enumeration.nextElement();
                if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
                    continue;
                }
                String className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
                className = className.replace("/",".");
                if(className.contains("HelloWorldServlet")) {
                    System.out.println(className);
                    external = cl.loadClass(className);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(HelloServlet.class);
        classes.add(external);

        return super.getClasses();
    }
}
```

don't work.

Is there a way to get it?

I want to load dynamically REST Endpoints from a JAR in a Servlet Container.

Comment: This sounds like a hack and a bad idea.  You should try to see if you can simply inlcude the required JARs on your classpath.

Comment: `return super.getClasses();`. Why? [That is an empty set](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.java#87). Don't you want to return the actual set you are creating?

Comment: If you want dynamic loading of your resource classes, you could use ServiceLoader mechanisms to discover and load them on startup. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Comment: @peeskillet That was a typo. My IDE autocomplete it for me. But when I change it to the right return, it is the same problem.

Comment: @Pandaabd I try it tommorow. Thanks.

Comment: @Tim I don't want a Hack. I only want a system where I can copy a JAR to a Directory, load it in Runtime and get the REST Endpoint from the loaded JAR. I think this should be a normal wish, to have a scaleable WebApp without to rebuild it every time.

Comment: This is not a normal request.  I suggest using something like JRebel rather than trying to build your own dynamic reloading.